# Javascript ajax queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, queue

can javascript provide nested queues?

my expected queue with ajax:

- Load Parent 1
- Load Child
- Load Child
- Load Child
- done
- Load Parent 2
- Load Child
- Load Child
- done

etc ..

so the next parent will waiting and be executed after the childs of the previous parent has finished.

I have tried to do it using the code below:

```
var Queue = function(handler) {
    var queue = [];

    var run = function() {
        var callback = function() {
            queue.shift();

            if(queue.length > 0) {
                run();
            }
        }

        handler(queue[0], callback);
    }

    this.append = function(task) {
        queue.push(task);
        if(queue.length === 1) {
            run();
        }
    }
}

var queue = new Queue(function(task, callback) {
    task(function() {
        if(task.callback) {
            task.callback();
        }
        callback();
    });
});
```

And this is my ajax call.

```
var actionGetImages = function(keywords) {
var getImagesTasks = [];

Object.keys(keywords).forEach(keywordKey => {
    getImagesTasks[keywordKey] = function(getImageCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url-get-images',
            data: {
                keyword: keywords[keywordKey].title,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var contents = JSON.parse(data);
                var getContentTasks = [];

                Object.keys(contents).forEach(contentKey => {
                    getContentTasks[contentKey] = function(getContentCallback) {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'url-get-content',
                            data: {
                                data: JSON.stringify(contents[contentKey])
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                getContentCallback();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                for(var i2 = 0; i2 < getContentTasks.length; i2++) {
                    queue.append(getContentTasks[i2]);
                }

                getImageCallback();
            }
        });
    }
});

for(var i1 = 0; i1 < getImagesTasks.length; i1++) {
    queue.append(getImagesTasks[i1]);
}
```

}

but the result from this code is not what i expected, it will be like below:

- Load Parent 1
- Load Parent 2
- Load Child
- Load Child
- Load Child
- done
- Load Child
- Load Child
- done

Comment: well, you do load the queue with Load Parent 1 and Load Parent 2 before any children are loaded into the queue

Comment: you can achieve what you want simply by using `async`/`await` - https://pastebin.com/C773xQsU

Comment: Wow it worked, now i can sleep well. thank you so much... @JaromandaX

Comment: the issue with your queue is that the parents are queued before the ajax even starts (that's asynchrony for you) - so of course they'll run first and second, Promises (which $.ajax return) and especially async/await make this sort of forced sequence a breeze, as you can see with how short the working code can be

Comment: yes, i see. i forget javascript have async/await. god bless u bro, thank you so much.

Comment: How do I handle errors? for example, if 1 process is in the url-get-content error, such as error 504, then the next process will still be executed.

Comment: wrap each `await $.ajax` in try/catch and put your error handling in the catch

Comment: I see bro.. noted